# Why is lamp D off?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

I understand the other lamps, but the answer for lamp d is that it is off as no current flows through it. I don't understand why? Please help.

Comment: Use Kirchoff's Laws.  Find the current flow thru each node and the voltage at each node.

Answer (score 2):

The left and right lamps, and the left and right cells, are identical. So the voltage drop across the lamps will be the same, and the voltage between the outer lamps will be the same as the voltage between the cells. So there's no difference in voltage across lamp d, so no current and it doesn't light.

Answer (score 0):

In case lamp $d$ circuit, there are 2 lamps / power unit. And in case of bigger outer circuit,- 1 lamp / power unit (cause 2 lamps and 2 power units). So $d$ lamp (inner-circuit) has greater electrical resistivity, and because current flows in such a path which has smaller resistance (same as for river flow),- it "chooses" outer circuit and skips inner circuit with lamp $d$. Thus lamp d with be off.

Comment: This is not entirely correct.


The current does not 'choose' ONLY the path of least resistance - it simply divides in inverse proportion to the resistance of the two paths. (In a parallel circuit you can se that there IS a current through the larger resistor)

The correct answer is given above - to paraphrase that:




The voltage drop across ONE  lamp is half the total voltage (because there are 2 lamps in series.) The upper node of D is at half the total voltage since it is the mid point of the 2 cells. Thus both ends of D are at the same voltage and no current flows.

Comment: In both cases (inner and outer circuit) there are 2 lamps, just in outer circuit there is 2 power supply units, instead of 1, this raises voltage in outer circuit and thus strengthens current flow in outer circuit. Of course my explanation is not ideal and current does not chooses where to flow, but is "forced" to flow better in less resistivity paths.

Comment: No - it is not the case that 'all the current flows in the outer circuit because there is more voltage/less resistance'. The answer is that there is ZERO potential difference across the inner lamp.